# Compose ModalBottomSheet with dynamic height and scrollable column could not dragging down when there is no extra space

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, bottom-sheet

#### What I want

1. Top fixed item with status bar padding and adaptive radius
2. Bottom fixed item with navigation bar padding
3. Adaptive center item, have enough room => Not scrollable, if not => scrollable

#### Current status

> For full demo [click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0gQt.jpg)

##### Only problem here is when there is no extra space, and we are dragging the scrollable list.

I think it's a bug, because everything is fine except the scrollable column.

- `window.height - sheetContent.height >= statusBarHeight`

  Everything is fine.

  [image]
- `window.height - sheetContent.height < statusBarHeight`

  - Dragging top fixed item or bottom fixed item, scroll still acting well.
  - Dragging the scrollable list, sheet pops back to top when the `sheetState.offset` is approaching statusBarHeight

  [image]

#### Test youself

You can test it with these 3 functions, for me, I'm using Pixel 2 Emulator, itemCount at `18,19` could tell the difference.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CEModalBottomSheet(
    sheetState: ModalBottomSheetState,
    onCloseDialogClicked: () -> Unit,
    title: String = "BottomSheet Title",
    toolbarElevation: Dp = 0.dp,
    sheetContent: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val sheetOffset = sheetState.offset
    val statusBar = WindowInsets.statusBars.asPaddingValues()

    val shapeRadius by animateDpAsState(
        if (sheetOffset.value < with(density) { statusBar.calculateTopPadding().toPx() }) {
            0.dp
        } else 12.dp
    )

    val dynamicStatusBarPadding by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            val statusBarHeightPx2 = with(density) { statusBar.calculateTopPadding().toPx() }
            val offsetValuePx = sheetOffset.value
            if (offsetValuePx >= statusBarHeightPx2) {
                0.dp
            } else {
                with(density) { (statusBarHeightPx2 - offsetValuePx).toDp() }
            }
        }
    }
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = sheetState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = shapeRadius, topEnd = shapeRadius),
        content = {},
        sheetContent = {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                TopTitleItemForDialog(
                    title = title,
                    elevation = toolbarElevation,
                    topPadding = dynamicStatusBarPadding,
                    onClick = onCloseDialogClicked
                )
                sheetContent()
            }

        })
}


@Composable
fun TopTitleItemForDialog(
    title: String,
    elevation: Dp = 0.dp,
    topPadding: Dp = 0.dp,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        color = Color.LightGray,
        elevation = elevation
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = topPadding),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))
            Text(
                text = title,
                maxLines = 1,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            IconButton(onClick = onClick) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Close,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.cancel),
                    tint = Color.Gray,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

class SheetPaddingTestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.statusBarColor = android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT
        window.navigationBarColor = android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        setContent {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Green), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                var itemCount by remember { mutableStateOf(20) }
                val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden) { false }
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                Text("显示弹窗", modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                    scope.launch { state.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded) }
                })
                CEModalBottomSheet(sheetState = state,
                    onCloseDialogClicked = {
                        scope.launch {
                            state.hide()
                        }
                    }, sheetContent = {
                        Column(
                            Modifier
                                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                                .weight(1f, fill = false)
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                        ) {
                            repeat(itemCount) {
                                Box(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .fillMaxWidth()
                                        .height(30.dp)
                                        .background(Color.Blue.copy(alpha = 1f - it * 0.04f))
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        CompositionLocalProvider(
                            LocalContentColor.provides(Color.White)
                        ) {
                            Row(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
                                    .padding(vertical = 12.dp)
                                    .navigationBarsPadding(),
                                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                            ) {

                                IconButton(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                                    onClick = {
                                        itemCount = max(itemCount - 1, 0)
                                    }) {
                                    Icon(Icons.Default.KeyboardArrowLeft, "")
                                }
                                Text(
                                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), text = "$itemCount",
                                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                                )
                                IconButton(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                                    onClick = {
                                        itemCount++
                                    }) {
                                    Icon(Icons.Default.KeyboardArrowRight, "")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```